# PHP CGI | IIS | Execute Permissions

Tags: php, iis, cgi, fastcgi

I have a PHP page which uses the shell_exec command:

```
$psscriptpath = "C:\inetpub\htdocs\school_panel\scripts\change.ps1";
            shell_exec("powershell.exe -executionpolicy remotesigned -File " . $psscriptpath . " -username \"" . $username . "\" -password \"" . $password . "\"");
```

However, when i submit the page aka have the code above executed, my page just times out ( never finishes loading until the time out timer is reached and i get this error):
[image]

http://puu.sh/aXEdY/22cc87310c.png

Now i have done some research and it appears that i need to somehow set some sort of executing script permissions/rights in IIS/PHP? mabey change some php.ini config? I really am not sure.

I have already tried adding permissions for powershell for IUSER and etc. I have even set the execution policy on powershell to remotesigned. It appears i have the FastCGI and CGI module installed on IIS.

I have also tried running the script via CMD using php and it WORKS, just not in the browser.

Regards

Comment: No one has any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is as simple as this:

`shell_exec("powershell.exe -executionpolicy remotesigned -File {$psscriptpath} -username {$username} -password {$password} < NUL");`

You do not need to surround parameters in double quotes, and in order to prevent powershell from hanging, you need to pass `< NUL` at the end of the line.

The `< NUL` will force the output from PowerShell back to PHP.